# Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

The function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x, y) = |xy|$.
Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$

So this is the answer that I got, I just wanted to know if it were possible to do it like this.

$f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0, y_0) \in int(\mathbb{R}^2)$ iff the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f(x_0, y_0)}{\partial x}$  and $\frac{\partial f(x_0, y_0)}{\partial y}$

$\lim_{(x,y)→(x_0,y_0)}$ $\frac{f(x, y) − f(x_0, y_0) − Df(x_0, y_0)((x, y) − (x_0, y_0)}{||(x, y) − (x_0, y_0)||} = 0$,
    where

$Df(x_0, y_0) := (\partial f(x_0, y_0)/\partial x,\ \partial f(x_0, y_0)/\partial y)$ <-- This is a Jacobian matrix

First, I have shown the partial derivatives around $(0,0)$ do exist. 
    $\frac{\partial f(x, 0)}{\partial x} = 0, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$
   $\frac{\partial f(0, y)}{\partial y} = 0, \forall y\in\mathbb{R}$

Now, that I know that the partial derivatives do exist. I only need to show that the limit from $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ does exist. This can be done by the epsilon delta method.

$\lim_{(x,y)→(0, 0)}$ $\frac{f(x, y) − f(0, 0) − Df(0, 0)((x, y) − (0, 0)}{||(x, y) − (0, 0)||} = 0$,

iff for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exist a $\delta>0$ s.t. for all $(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}<\delta$ one has $\varepsilon$ > $\frac{|xy|}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}$.

....
So, I know that $|x|<=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ since $y^2\geq0$, so $|x|/(x^2+y^2)^{1/2} \leq 1$, $|xy|/(x^2+y^2)^{1/2} \leq |y| \leq (x^2+y^2)^{1/2} < \delta = \varepsilon$.

Hence, for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $\forall x,y$ such that $(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}<\delta$ one has $|xy|/(x^2+y^2)^{1/2} < \varepsilon$

One last question, is it possible to show that the limit exist with different delta and epsilon for one you want to show that the differentiate exist? For instance delta<2epsilon works also.

P.S.: I apologize for the format.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: At some parts I am not sure what you meant to write, @Gauss

Comment: Thanks for the edit Iulia, could you please tell me which parts. I can edit it, fore more clearity.

Comment: Before you introduce the jacobian matrix

Comment: Is it more clear? I made a mistake in the equation of the limit, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this similar problem http://math.colorado.edu/~radulesc/teaching_Fall2012/2400_notes/class-14-8.pdf.

Comment: Thanks again, will look into it.